# ggplot - facet by function output

Tags: r, facet, ggplot2

I'm unsure how to facet by a function of the data in the `data` element of a `ggplot` object.  In the following toy example, what I want to do is something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:8, y=runif(8), z=8:1)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap( ~ (z %% 2))
```

But that gives the error: `Error in layout_base(data, vars, drop = drop) :  At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting`.

I can achieve the desired result by transforming the data frame:

```
ggplot(transform(df, z=z%%2), aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap( ~ z)
```

but often it's desirable to not use such a transformation, for instance if I've already been given a `ggplot` object and I want to add some ad-hoc faceting to it.

Answer (score 3):

this sounds familiar to me, but I never managed to fix it - I think facet variable handling is just less powerful than aesthetic variable handling.

Addressing your root requirement - to ad-hoc facet an existing ggplot; note that you can replace wholesale the (master) data set of an existing `R` ggplot - for instance

```
myplot %+% transform(myplot$data, z=z%%2)
```

Comment: `myplot$data$zz <- myplot$data$z%%2` may be even more straightforward.

Comment: @Josh, true, but relies on the data set already being installed.  Sometimes I build ggplots with no data and then apply multiple data sets.

Comment: That's remarkably like the solution I've been using too - `myplot$data <- transform(myplot$data, z=z%%2)` .  I got namespace-burned a couple times by `%+%` because some other package defined the same operator.  Took me *hours* to figure that out.